# Tuning C hyper parameter in Soft Margin SVM in Matlab

Tags: classification, svm, optimization, matlab, hyperparameter

How to tune the C 'BoxConstraint'  hyperparameter in soft margin SVM to get the best optimal value?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to tune a single hyperparameter is to use what is called the elbow method. Do the following:

- Define a range of C you want to try, i.e `C = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, ...]`
- Loop over all values of C in your range

  - Train a new model with the current value of C
  - Evaluate each model on the validation set and store the results
- Plot your metric over over your range of C's

If you didn't choose a too narrow range you should visually see your optimal value of C by finding the value that either minimize or maximize your metric.

[image]

If you need to tune C alongside other hyperparameters you can use strategies such as grid search, randomized search or bayesian search.

Comment: I think you mean Validation Set. One should never use the test set for hyperparameter tuning!

Comment: You are correct. Thank you for noticing! Edited and corrected.

Comment: I am using 10 fold cross-validation with test and train partitions. so I don't have validation set. is it applicable to use it?

Comment: there is 'OptimizeHyperparameters' function in matlab that uses  Bayesian Optimization to generate good parameters. Do you think it is suitable for the linear soft margin SVM ? https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/optimize-an-svm-classifier-fit-using-bayesian-optimization.html

Comment: Yes, it is still applicable but any time you want to perform tuning you need to set aside some validation data to do it on. This applies regardless of the method you use to tune.

Comment: If you just tune one parameter I would use the elbow method or perhaps grid search (which will do the elbow method if you only have one parameter).

Comment: If you have more than one I would go with grid search or random search over baysian optimization. But use the one you find simplest to get working since the results are like not to differ that much.

Comment: usually in soft margin SVM, we tune the 'boxconstrain' the C value correct? while in RBF model, we tune the gamma and the C.

Comment: Tune gamma for non-linear SVMs, skip it for linear SVMs. But the comment section should not be used for asking new questions. Instead create a new question. Also, don't forget to mark an answer as correct if it solved your question (not necessarily me, but referring to your question history in general). Good luck!